# When run program he is asking for one more variable that I didnt asked

Tags: c

In this firs enter hours minutes and seconds I want from user to enter 3 variables but when i run program computer is asking for fourth, i dont know why :S Anybody ?

(It si asking for more detail) .................................

...........aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaa

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int d,m,vrst,vrmn,vrsc,nvrst;

    printf("Please enter hours minutes and seconds in Sarajevo : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d ", &vrst, &vrmn, &vrsc);

    printf("Please enter date and time ");
    scanf("%d %d", &d, &m);

     if(m<3)
            {
              nvrst=vrst+2;
              printf("Time in Sarajevo is %d %d %d ", nvrst, vrmn, vrsc);
            }
     if(m==3 && d<31)
            {
              nvrst=vrst+1;
              printf("Time in Sarajevo is %d %d %d ", nvrst, vrmn, vrsc);
            }
    if(m==3 && d==31)
            {
              nvrst=vrst+2;
              printf("Time in Sarajevo is %d %d %d ", nvrst, vrmn, vrsc);
            }

    if(m>3 && m<=9 )
            {
              nvrst=vrst+2;
              printf("Time in Sarajevo is %d %d %d ", nvrst, vrmn, vrsc);
            }
    if(m==10 && d<27)
            {
              nvrst=vrst+2;
              printf("Time in Sarajevo is %d %d %d ", nvrst, vrmn, vrsc);
            }
    if(m==10 && d>=27)
            {
              nvrst=vrst+1;
              printf("Time in Sarajevo is %d %d %d ", nvrst, vrmn, vrsc);
            }
    if(m>10)
            {
              nvrst=vrst+1;
              printf("Time in Sarajevo is  %d %d %d ", nvrst, vrmn, vrsc);
            }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post an example output of the program, including the input. To me, the code looks ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its

```
 scanf("%d %d %d", &vrst, &vrmn, &vrsc);
 and scanf("%d %d", &d, &m);
```

Remove those spaces between %d specifiers in `scanf`

**Is scanf("%d%d",...) different from scanf("%d %d",...)?**

They differ, but so subtly that it's a difference that
makes no difference

Suppose the input is " 12\t34\n". The "%d%d" format
matches this input as follows: The first "%d" skips the leading
white spaces and consumes and converts the 12, then the second
"%d" skips the tab and consumes and converts the 34. The newline
is left unread.

The "%d %d" format operates just a little differently, but
has the same outcome. The first "%d" skips the leading spaces
and converts the 12, then the space in the format matches and
skips the tab, then the second "%d" skips nothing and converts
the 34. As before, the newline is left unread.

Comment: The program is basically expecting a space since he specified it in his format. The following input would also work:  "12 12 12 "  notice the space after last 12.

Answer (score 1):

The last space on first scanf() is the problem:

```
scanf("%d %d %d ", &vrst, &vrmn, &vrsc);
```

Remove it and your program will work as you want.

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &vrst, &vrmn, &vrsc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove all the spaces in `scanf`. Just remove the last one

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &vrst, &vrmn, &vrsc);
               ^ - Remove this space
```